# Is ` token` value for Sanity.io projects optional?

Tags: javascript, next.js, sanity

I came across two tutorial using **Sanity.io** and one did not use the `project token` whereas the other used it, so how can we know what project must we provide it ?

Comment: it's probably documented somewhere - never trust random tutorials though - 99% of them are garbage

Comment: If you're configuring a `client` on your app which you will use to make write operations on your dataset then you should use a `token`. If you are just going to read public documents and edit them in sanity's studio then you don't need it. You can read more on [Sanity's docs](https://www.sanity.io/docs/http-auth). There are other situations in which you should consider using a token.